# Escape is not working with optional parameters !

Tags: sql-server

in my optional parameter query that uses LIKE operator , Escape special characters is not working .
this is part of the query

```
NAME LIKE  CASE WHEN '%'+@Name+'%' IS NULL THEN NAME ELSE '%'+@Name+'%' END
```

i thought i can make it like

```
NAME LIKE CASE WHEN '%'+@Name+'%'ESCAPE '\' IS NULL THEN NAME ELSE '%'+@Name+'%' END
```

but when i add escape '\' but it raise an error .
any help ??

Demo Code :

```
 set @Name='Restaur\[ant'

      SELECT      [JOB].HOUSE_CODE,  [JOB].JOB_CODE,  [JOB].OPEN_DATE,  [JOB].NAME AS Position,  [JOB].DESCRIPTION,  [RESTAURANT].ZIP_CODE AS ZipCode, 
                           [STATE].STATE_NAME AS State,  [RESTAURANT].CITY_NAME AS City
    FROM          [JOB] INNER JOIN
                           [RESTAURANT] ON  [JOB].HOUSE_CODE =  [RESTAURANT].HOUSE_CODE INNER JOIN
                           [STATE] ON  [RESTAURANT].STATE_CODE =  [STATE].STATE_CODE INNER JOIN
                           [JOB_CODE] ON  [JOB].HOUSE_CODE =  [JOB_CODE].HOUSE_CODE AND  [JOB].JOB_CODE =  [JOB_CODE].JOB_CODE AND 
                           [RESTAURANT].HOUSE_CODE =  [JOB_CODE].HOUSE_CODE
    WHERE     (  [JOB].NAME LIKE  CASE WHEN '%'+@Name+'%' IS NULL THEN  [JOB].NAME ELSE '%'+@Name+'%' END ESCAPE '\' )
```

Comment: Maybe you'd just write what you are trying to achieve? It's hard to answer something which isn't a question.

Comment: Provide Enough Code Details for demonstrate

Answer (score 5):

Put the ESCAPE outside of the CASE statement. Also, it's sufficient to just test @Name for NULL.

```
NAME LIKE CASE WHEN @Name IS NULL THEN NAME ELSE '%'+@Name+'%' END ESCAPE `\`
```

**EDIT**: Here's some demo code to illustrate the technique.

```
declare @test table (
    name varchar(100)
)

insert into @test
    (name)
    select 'I am 100% confident this works.' union all
    select 'There can be no doubt.' union all
    select 'I would like to eat in fine restaur[ant some day.'

declare @name varchar(100)

/* Case when @name is NULL */
select name
    from @test
    where name like case when @name is null then name else '%'+@name+'%' end escape '\'

set @name = '100\%'

/* Case when @name has a value with a % */
select name
    from @test
    where name like case when @name is null then name else '%'+@name+'%' end escape '\'

set @name = 'restaur\[ant'

/* Case when @name has a value with a [ */
select name
    from @test
    where name like case when @name is null then name else '%'+@name+'%' end escape '\'
```

Comment: @Ali Nour: I've added some demo code to my answer to illustrate that the technique works.

Comment: Thanks man but its still not working on [ , i insert Restaur[ant ans it does not read the row.

Comment: @Ali Nour: I've added your restaurant example into the demo code.

Comment: are you sure that it return the row containing restaur\[ant because mine it doesn`t.

Comment: @Ali Nour: Yes. The demo code I've provided returns the row with restaur[ant in the third select. Just for fun, I even tested it in 2000, 2005 and 2008 instances. It works in all three environments.

Comment: @Ali Nour: The only thing that I see in your code is the possible misspelling. You have the word restaurant ending in 'ent' instead of 'ant'

Comment: @Ali Nour: The syntax looks fine. Are you sure your `[JOB].NAME` column contains a value with 'Restaur[ant' in it? Are you not getting the row back because one of you inner joins is not matching? Try to isolate this at it's simplest form. Does this return results: `SELECT * FROM [JOB] WHERE NAME LIKE '%Restaur%'`

Comment: @Ali Nour: It's got to be one of your inner joins excluding the row then. Remove them all and run the simplified query to verify you get results. Then add them back one at a time until you find the offending one.

Comment: the query was working well. but then i found the [ issue so i add the ESCAPE '[' .

Comment: @Ali Nour: I'm stumped at this point. Please post if you figure it out as I'll be curious to know what the resolution was.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a space before `ESCAPE`?

```
+'%'ESCAPE '\' IS
```

to this:

```
+'%' ESCAPE '\' IS
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for it to do? I tried your first example and it behaved the way I would expect it to:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
NAME varchar(100)
)

GO

INSERT test2(name) values('Fred')
INSERT test2(name) values('bert')

GO
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100)
--SET @name='re'
SELECT * FROM test2
WHERE NAME LIKE CASE WHEN '%'+@Name+'%' IS NULL THEN NAME ELSE '%'+@Name+'%' END
```

If I supply a value for @Name it only returns names containing that value, if I leave it out it returns all names?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to compare '%'+@Name+'%ESCAPE'\' to null? I think you want to put the escape keyword later on, like so:

```
CASE WHEN '%'+@Name+'%' IS NULL THEN NAME ELSE '%'+@Name+'%' ESCAPE '\' END
```

Comment: The problem is that without Escape it doesn`t read and row that contains cells that contain [ . so im trying to use ESCAPe to avoid that.